# How do I install Python on Windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: python, 32-bit, windows-7-embedded

I went to the link here, [python 3.8 download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3814/), but there is no installer executable. How can I get the normal python installer download for older versions as is available on the most recent page?

(edit) If this is a bad question, feel free to explain why. Python.org made it difficult to download installers for old versions, hence this question. Thanks.

Comment: It is a bad question because it is a question about how to navigate a web page, not a question about how to install the software. If you look at the [main Windows downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), you can clearly see that there are "no files for this release" for 3.8.14. The 3.8 branch is only available on Windows up to 3.8.10, which you discover by continuing to read that page. Do note that this is most likely the *last* version of Python that will ever support Windows 7. Please upgrade. Microsoft has not supported Windows 7 for years, either.

Comment: Also, it says right there *on the page you linked*: "According to the release calendar specified in PEP 569, Python 3.8 is now in the "security fixes only" stage of its life cycle: 3.8 branch only accepts security fixes and releases of those are made irregularly in source-only form until October 2024. Python 3.8 isn't receiving regular bug fixes anymore, and binary installers are no longer provided for it. **Python 3.8.10 was the last full bugfix release of Python 3.8 with binary installers.**" (Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install this one, it has 32-bit for windows [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/)